# scraping attribute under tag

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

response:

```
['<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top">\r\n                        LINAIA\r\n                    </td>',
 '<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top" title="rodrigue@linaia.com">\r\n                        PAILLEREAU  Florent \r\n        
            </td>',
 '<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top">\r\n                        35000 RENNES\r\n                    </td>',
 '<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top">\r\n                        \r\n                    </td>',
 '<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top" align="center">\r\n                        \n                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(\'index.cfm?fuseaction=mEnt.ficheEntAW&amp;uuid=2f89094e-4da1-4e1b-9ada-c16cea5e25f9&amp;affDoc=false\',\'ficheEntreprise\',\'scrollbars=yes,width=700,height=750\')">Fiche</a>\n                \r\n                    </td>']
```

I want to extract the value "rodrigue@linaia.com".

I have css selector as below

```
email = response.css('td::attr(title)')[1].get()
```

but this is not working and I am getting below error and I don't understand why

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [43], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 all.css('td::attr(title)')[1].get().strip()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py:70, in SelectorList.__getitem__(self, pos)
     69 def __getitem__(self, pos):
---> 70     o = super(SelectorList, self).__getitem__(pos)
     71     return self.__class__(o) if isinstance(pos, slice) else o

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I think it may be zero based, try [0] instead of [1]

Comment: no [0] is the first td tag .

Comment: I don't know the language you are using, but it seems to me that the index is applied after finding all tds with attr title.  Ergo, it should be 0.  Have you tried `0`?

Comment: yes tried .  0 doesn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your html is strange but I've recreated your problem and used python + BeautifulSoup to get an answer using a try/except to find the tag that has a 'title' attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp  = ['<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top">\r\n                        LINAIA\r\n                    </td>',
 '''<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top" title="rodrigue@linaia.com">\r\n                        PAILLEREAU  Florent \r\n        
            </td>''',
 '<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top">\r\n                        35000 RENNES\r\n                    </td>',
 '<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top">\r\n                        \r\n                    </td>',
 '<td class="V2ligneB" valign="top" align="center">\r\n                        \n                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open(\'index.cfm?fuseaction=mEnt.ficheEntAW&amp;uuid=2f89094e-4da1-4e1b-9ada-c16cea5e25f9&amp;affDoc=false\',\'ficheEntreprise\',\'scrollbars=yes,width=700,height=750\')">Fiche</a>\n                \r\n                    </td>']

for row,html in enumerate(resp):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    try:
        email = soup.find('td')['title']
        print(email)
    except KeyError:
        print(f'Not found in row: {row}')
```